# Accuracy of A Equivalence about Absolutely Convex Sets

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

I remember I’ve seen a theorem but I’m not sure about remembering it truthfully or not. I cannot find this equivalence in anywhere. That is the reason of my doubt. Is it true or not? If it is true how should I show it via using definitions below? Could someone share exact theorem and proof or its link? If there is a mistake please fix me. Thanks a lot

> Let $X$ be a vector space over $\mathcal F$ field (it is real or complex numbers) and $A \subseteq X$
>
> **$A$ is absolutely convex if and only if A is convex and balanced**

Let $\lambda , \beta \in \mathcal F$ and $x,y \in A$

- If $|\lambda| + |\beta| \le 1$ such that $\lambda x+ \beta y \in A$ then $A$ is an absolutely convex set
- If $\lambda x \in A$ such that $|\lambda| \le 1$ then A is balanced set
- If $\lambda x + (1- \lambda )y \in A$ such that $|\lambda| \in [0,1] $ then A is convex set

Comment: The trick is to write $\lambda=|\lambda| \sigma$ with the sign $\sigma=\lambda/|\lambda|$ if $\lambda\neq 0$ (and $\sigma=1$ else).

Comment: @Jochen very thanks sir. I couldn’t understand very well what did you mean “and $\sigma=1 $ else” Does it mean $\sigma \neq 1$?

Comment: else refers to the case $\lambda=0$.

Comment: @Jochen thanks again